# On Windows, putting lines with P results in the * register at the end of current line instead of the " register and shifting the current line down

Tags: cut-copy-paste, microsoft-windows

I use the same configuration on Windows as I do on Linux. It works normally on Linux but on Windows (vim and gvim) I am getting this odd behavior when putting lines with `P`:

Steps:

1. I yank a line with `Y` in Normal Mode
2. I go to another line and put it using `P`. I expect the contents of the `"` register to be pasted on the current line, with the contents of the current line shifted to the line below. This is what happens on Linux with the same configuration. Instead, the contents of the `*` register gets pasted on the end of the current line.

If I don't get anyone here telling me that they know what the problem might be I will have to find the problem through the process of elimination.

Comment: I'm using Vim 9.0 on Windows 10 and `P` past the line yanked in front of the current line.

Comment: `I yank a line with Y in Normal Mode` `Y` is equivalent of `y$`, not `yy`, except for **Neovim** defaults.

Comment: @Mat I try on bare version of Vim 9.0 or Vim 8.2 and I have `Y` behaving like `yy` instead of `y$` (`set nocompatible` is part of `_vimrc`)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt My bad, the other way round: `Y` is the same as `yy`, except if it was mapped to `y$` (user config or Neovim defaults, etc.). The OP should try `yy` anyway, as the words "same config" are often misleading. `Y` gets remapped quite often.

Comment: What about `:verbose set clipboard?` ? More generally, [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You were right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My configuration is split into different files, so I renamed one at a time to disable them. When I found the file with the problem setting I commented out half of it, found the problem had gone and then through further elimation I found the culprit:

```
set clipboard+=unnamedplus
```

> `:help unnnamedplus`
> unnamedplus   A variant of the "unnamed" flag
> which uses the            clipboard register '+' (quoteplus) instead of
> register '*' for all yank, delete, change and put           operations
> which would normally go to the unnamed            register.  When "unnamed" is
> also included to the          option, yank operations (but not delete,
> change or             put) will additionally copy the text into register
> '*'.            Only available with the +X11 feature.           Availability can
> be checked with: >
> if has('unnamedplus')

Comment: You might consider citing part of `:help clipboard` and explaining why this caused the issue you saw